# formHelper type time : avoiding the annoying dropdown select input?

Tags: html, forms, cakephp

When i use the cakePHP form helper for a type 'time' field, it automatically generates a dropdown select input and not an easy&easy html5 type time keyboard input [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_time)

Anyone has a quick solution to this ? (preferably without any javascript)

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, finally i used a jQuery timepicker, that's working fine ! [find it here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)
And after importing the css and js through cakePHP, it's very easy to use.

**For example:**

With an form element like this (note the type => text)

```
echo $this->Form->input('time', array(
'type'=>'text',
'label'=>'Réel',
'div'=> array(
'class'=>'two columns')
));
```

you just call it with

```
<script>
    $('#TimeID').timepicker();
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just lock the type by manually adding it.
So if you want to use a text field for JS snippets:

```
echo $this->Form->input('time', array('type' => 'text'));
```

You can also make it anything else (manually).

For "time" you can try

```
echo $this->Form->input('time', array('type' => 'time'));
```

Don't forget to adjust your data form input if necessary.

But careful with HTML5 stuff. This is not suitable for all browsers and therefore can lead to problems in some.

Comment: There's no way of getting this result easily then ?
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_time